# Cannot edit boot priority

Tags: windows-10, bios

I am unable to edit the boot priority in order to run linux using a bootable sd

I have restarted my computer and entered the bios menu but under boot there is no option for boot priority.

I am running windows 10 if that helps can someone please help me.

Thank you in advance

UPDATE:
my manufacturer is lenovo and my model is 80E3

My bios version is a2cn34ww v2.02

Comment: Too little info to answer: what PC make and model? Have you looked at user manual?

Comment: I don't have a user manual

Comment: Send a shot of your bios, will you?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer after a great deal of time and here it is for those of you who are having the same problem.

Under the boot menu on BIOS select the first option and choose the 'legacy support' option from the dropdown exit and save changes plug in a usb harddrive with your bootable image and a menu should come up with four options. One for the internal harddrive
And another slightly different one for the internal harddrive, one for the cd drive and another for the usb drive select the latter and then select your os.

Hope this was clear and could help you I'll leave this question as is so that if someone has a better answer I can accept theirs.